Selenium Python, my copy paste method doesn't work
I am trying to get the string from text box s and copy paste it into text box b, then return from text box b.
a is the driver, b and s are different text boxes.
def workaround(a, b, s):
    b.clear()
    actions = ActionChains(a)
    actions.click(s)
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
    actions.send_keys("a")
    actions.send_keys("c")
    actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
    actions.click(b)
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
    actions.send_keys("v")
    actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
    actions.perform()
    
    result = b.get_attribute('value')
    return result

This returns a blank space. If I remove the b.clear() then it returns the original value of b. If I remove actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL) and actions.key_up(Keys.CONTROL) then 'v' is returned.
edit to make reproducible:
def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    url = 'https://www.gps-coordinates.net/'
    browser.get(url)
    address = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'address')
    address.clear()
    address.send_keys('this shouldnt show up')
    button = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn.btn-primary')
    button.click()
    lat = browser.find_element(By.ID,'latitude')
    lat_value = workaround(browser, address, lat)
    print(lat_value)
    return lat_value


Can you please [edit] the question and make the code a [mcve]?

Is there a reason why you need to be emulating copy-paste shortcuts? Does this not work for you: inp = s.get_attribute('value');
d.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{inp}')", b);
return b.get_attribute('value')

Robert, I have updated the question. ryyyn, I tried that approach and it did not work. It returned the unchanged value of b.

just use send_keys... ex: s.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v");

@browsermator that doesn't work, I already tried.

ctrl-a and/or ctrl-c may not work, but paste should.  You can use your native code to write to the clipboard.

@browsermator I already checked, paste doesn't work for me either.

you might try  s.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v"); instead?  (I don't know python myself but according to another thread it should work)

why dont get text as variable and then write it. Also had you tried to call perform() for each action? ctrl+a -> perform(). ctrl+c -> perform() ...

@wonka calling perform() after each function did not work. I am doing this process because getting text as a variable was not working.
